Query view from BigQuery to temporal table so it could be consumed by Storage API
I want to use Storage API to read a lot of rows from a view on bigQuery.
I'm using Java :)
There is a limitation on Storage API, it cannot consume from views. (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage#limitations)
So my question is, how can I query it?
Is there a simple way of creating a temporal table with my query and getting that tableId  so I can use StorageAPI to read from there?

I suppose that you are using Storage Read API for a better performance? But when you add an additional step with storage of the view results in a temporal table it won't be faster. Instead, get the SQL definition of the view and use it as a query for the Storage Read API.
Disclaimer: I'm not an expert of BigQuery. This is just an idea. Hope it helps.
